# How to add control on SkiaSharp

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, skiasharp

I have a floor plan (.svg format) and I want to load this svg with `SkiaSharp`, so that I could zoom-in and zoom out. ([this guy's documentation was very helpful](https://pshul.com/2018/02/01/xamarin-forms-interactive-svg-image-using-skiasharp-with-pan-and-zoom/))

I will put a pin on svg (on SkiaSharp)

I created `AbsoluteLayout` and `ImageButton` and used `AbsoluteLayout.SetLayoutBounds` method. This worked.

But, this is actually not skiasharp's control, this is forms control. I have a coordinates on svg and I will use skiasharp svg's coordinates . How can I add a layer by layer control on skiasharp, or does skiasharp have a control for this?

Comment: Is this what you are doing, 1. Use SkiaSharp to display image. 2. Add another View(Pin) above the SVG image. Am I correct?

Comment: @Nikhileshwar yes

Comment: SkiaSharp is just a drawing tool, what you need is to create a xamarin custom control and use skia canvas inside to show content. This is doable just using forms, or you might need custom renderers to have more control over pinch gestures.